# how to change "ImageView" opacity in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-imageview

I want to change the opacity of an image View.
I know how to change opacity in Java but how should I do in kotlin?

Comment: Could you provide a code example including what library or package is providing the `ImageView` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
val imageView = ImageView(context)
imageView.alpha = 0.75f
```